# Javascript Dictionary problems

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I am creating a javascript based "favourite assignment" list for my photo app which I have created using phonegap.

I'm basing it on a "to-do list" tutorial code and have tried to adapt it to my purposes.

There are two variables: the title (text) and the link (text2)

It works great in a browser, and on first launch in the app. 
But on refresh or relaunch, I dont think it's saving the link variable to the dictionary.

would appreciate any guidance with the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

    //Create a new To-Do
    function createNewToDo()
    {
        var todoDictionary = {};
        //Prompt the user to enter To-Do
        var todo="FAST SHUTTER SPEEDS";
        var todolink="#fastshutter";
        if (todo!=null)
        {
            if (todo == "")
            {
                alert("To-Do can't be empty!");
            }
            else
            {
                //Append the new To-Do with the table
                todoDictionary = { check : 0 , text : todo , text2 : todolink};
                addTableRow(todoDictionary,false);
            }
        }

    }


    //Add a row to the table
    var rowID = 0;
    function addTableRow(todoDictionary, appIsLoading)
    {

        rowID +=1;
        var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        //Set up the CheckBox
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "deleteButton";
        element1.value = "X";

        element1.setAttribute("onclick","deleteSelectedRow(this)");
        element1.className = "deleteButton";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);


        //Set up the View Button
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "viewButton";
        element2.value = todoDictionary["text"];
        var link = todoDictionary["text2"];
        element2.id = rowID;
        element2.onclick=function(){ window.location.hash = link; };
        element2.className = "viewButton";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);

        //Save & Update UI
        saveToDoList();

        if (!appIsLoading)
        alert("Assignment Added To Favourite List!");
    }




    //Deletes current row
    function deleteSelectedRow(deleteButton)
    {
        var p=deleteButton.parentNode.parentNode;
        p.parentNode.removeChild(p);
        saveToDoList();
    }




    function saveToDoList()
    {
        //Create a todoArray
        var todoArray = {};
        var checkBoxState = 0;
        var textValue = "";
        var text2Value = "";

        //Get current table
        var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        if (rowCount != 0)
        {
            //Loop through all rows
            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
            {
                var row = table.rows[i];

                //Add checkbox state
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)
                {
                    checkBoxState = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    checkBoxState= 0;
                }


                //Add text data
                var textbox = row.cells[1].childNodes[0];
                textValue = textbox.value;


                //Fill the array with check & text data
                todoArray["row"+i] =
                {
                    check : checkBoxState,
                    text : textValue
                };

            }
        }
        else
        {
            todoArray = null;
        }

        //Use local storage to persist data
        //We use JSON to preserve objects

        window.localStorage.setItem("todoList", JSON.stringify(todoArray));
    }



    function loadToDoList()
    {

        //Get the saved To-Do list array by JSON parsing localStorage
        var theList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("todoList"));


        if (null == theList || theList=="null")
        {
            deleteAllRows();
        }
        else
        {
            var count = 0;
            for (var obj in theList)
            {
                count++;
            }

            //Clear table
            deleteAllRows();
            //Loop through all rows
            for(var i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                //Add row
                addTableRow(theList["row"+i],true);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: When you relaunch an application it is likely wiping out the localStorage allocated for the previous instance. As for refreshing in the browser, what makes you think it's not saving? Have you run `window.localStorage.getItem("todoList")` in your browser's JS console?

Comment: it isn't wiping it out, it is reloading the list the next time the app is loaded with the correct titles and numbers of favourite assignments. 
phonegap transfers it from local storage to the permanent iphone storage. 
it's saving the title (text) but not saving the link (text2).
the links will work fine as long as I dont refresh the entire index.html (it's one big html doc with separate divs) then it says "Undefined" or as long as the app remains active...on relaunch, links dont work

Comment: Have you verified that `textbox` and `textbox.value` are valid values prior to saving? If so, what is an example value?

Comment: I believe so. 
 if I put "text2" for example as the title, the link (#fastshutter.html) shows up as the title name.

Comment: the example code I am basing this on unmodified works perfect, but I've added a second text element(the link) and that is the main difference.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in the `saveToDoList` function you aren't adding your text2 value to the array of objects that's saved to localStorage:

```
todoArray["row"+i] =
{
      check : checkBoxState,
      text : textValue
};
```

Should be:

```
todoArray["row"+i] =
{
      check : checkBoxState,
      text : textValue,
      link : // get the value of your link
};
```

Since you haven't posted the associated HTML I cannot tell you how to get the value of the link

Comment: There needs to be a comma after `text : textValue`